# Add class based on previous one jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jquery code, what it does that on button click, it adds a class to a link "active" to first element, when i presses the button again it will add class to second element and so on. It check the class in prevoious element and add class to next element. I am new so i am stuck

```
$(".click").click(function(){

  $('.pg').each(function() {
  if($('.pg').hasClass('selected')){
  $('.pg').addClass('selected');
  });

});
```

Comment: do you want to remove teh class form the previous one

Comment: no, just add to next one based on previous one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will find the first element that has class 'pg' but not 'selected' and add 'selected' to it

```
$(".click").click(function() {
  $('.pg:not(.selected):eq(0)').addClass('selected')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if previous element has class and adding it to the next one is pointless. In short words - all elements will have this class if the first one has it too. Just try with:

```
$(".click").click(function(){

  $('.pg').toggleClass('selected', $('.pg:first').hasClass('selected'));

});
```